# Firefox jQuery form submission not working

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox, form-submit

```
var makeField = function(name, value) {
    return $('<input />').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: name,
        value: value
    });
};

$('.login').on('click', function() {
    var form = $('<form />').attr('method', 'POST');

    form.append(makeField('n0', 'data1'));
    form.append(makeField('n1', 'data2'));
    form.append(makeField('n2', 'data3'));

    $(document).append(form);
    form.submit();
});
```

The above code works fine in Safari, Chrome and Opera but firefox ignores `form.submit();`. I tested the above code by adding `console.log('...');` above and below the submit call, and it executes without error. I also tried calling `$(form).submit();`, and I get the same unwanted result.

Has anyone ran into this before, or have a solution?

Comment: Be more jQuery friendly, try changing `var form = document.createElement('form');` to `var form = $("<form />").attr('method', 'POST');`

Comment: The key part is that jQuery's append() silently does nothing when called on a non-element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Updated with your new code

```
$(function() {
    var makeField = function(name, value) {
        return $('<input />').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            name: name,
            value: value
        });
    };

     $(document).on('click', '.login', function() {
        var form = $("<form />").attr({ method: "POST" }).append(
                makeField('n0', 'data1'),
                makeField('n1', 'data2'),
                makeField('n2', 'data3')
            );

        // just adding a callback on submit here to show it works
        form.submit(function(e){ alert("Submitting Form"); });

        $("body").append(form);
        form.submit();
    });
})
```

See [WORKING jsFiddle in FF HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/YmDG3/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the code cleanup, but that didn't solve my firefox issue.

Comment: fyi just edited it with explination, would really need to see more of what you're doing to determine problem, i assume that isn't your code entirely, but in pieces?

Comment: I modified my original code to include your edits, as well as what it actually looks like and the only thing that changes are the names and values of the fields.

Comment: fyi, the main fix was changing `$(document)` to `$("body")`

Comment: Yeah, after changing to `$(body)` firefox now submits the form. Thanks very much!

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem: It turns out there is a bug in FireFox that causes .submit() to be ignored under certain circumstances. Here is a workaround: `var button = $("<input type='submit' style='display: none'/>"); form.append(button); button.trigger('click');`