# Why does this javascript code for submitting a form not work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wanted to remove buttons on a form submission to let users know that "it's being worked on ...".  I wrote some javascript to do the work as well as a python function to set things up server side.  Here is a resulting html example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function proceed_validate() {
    return true;
}
function form_button_reenable(span) {
    "use strict";
    var att = Object.create(null);

    att.id = span.getAttribute('data-id');
    att.value = span.getAttribute('data-value');
    att.style = span.getAttribute('data-style');

    span.innerHTML = "<input type=submit class=form_button onclick=\\"form_button_disable(this);\\" id=\\"" + att.id + "\\" value=\\"" + att.value + "\\" style=\\"" + att.style + "\\" />";
    return;
}
function form_button_disable(button) {
    "use strict";
    var span = button.parentElement,
        form = button.form;

    if (span.id !== "span_" + button.id) {
        alert("HTML not formatted as expected.");
        return;
    }

    if (span.getAttribute('data-buttonreplace') === "true") {
        span.innerHTML = "<em>" + span.getAttribute('data-changetext') + "</em>";
    } else {
        button.disabled = true;
        button.value = span.getAttribute('data-changetext');
    }

    // Run the form's onsubmit event if there is one.
    // The onSubmit event doesn't do a submission, just validation.
    if (form.onsubmit !== null) {
        // The onSubmit event may do validation, if it failed, revert
        if (!form.onsubmit()) {
            // Some forms don't want to be reverted
            if (span.getAttribute('data-autorevert') == "true") {
                // Use the attributes in the span tag to recreate the <input> tag.
                form_button_reenable(span);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    form.submit();
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <FORM ACTION="order-review.cgi" METHOD=post onsubmit="return proceed_validate();"> 
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
      <span id="span_place_order" data-id="place_order" data-value="Place Order" data-style="line-height:17px;" data-buttonreplace="true" data-changetext="<b>Verifying order ...</b>" data-autorevert="true">
         <input type=submit id="place_order" class=form_button style="line-height:17px;" value="Place Order" onclick="return form_button_disable(this);"/>
      </span>
    </FORM>
  </body>
</html>
```

This worked (great) on my test server, but about 20-30% of the users of the website get stuck with the form never submitting.

For my on edification, is there a more portable way to do this that doesn't involve jquery? (That's  a site policy)

**Edit**
Turns out the problem is isolated to Firefox.  At least Firefox v26 and v27.  I didn't bother testing beyond that.

**Edit II**
Something (rather, nothing) happens when the `form.submit();` function is invoked.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I don't suppose some of those users have indicated any error messages, or at least which browsers they're using, have they?

Comment: @PaulRichter Firefox.  It doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @cookiemonster I did, and went through the logs.  Turns out it's Firefox.

Comment: @cookiemonster Nothing.  The browser just stops when the `form.submit();` command is parsed.

Comment: @Jamie If you step through the code in firebug, are you certain its not hitting one of those `return` statements?

Comment: Also, I just found [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108330/firefox-jquery-form-submission-not-working#comment-21053327). Does that help at all? (I know they're showing jQuery, but you should be able to adapt it for plain JavaScript, assuming the suggestion makes sense).

Comment: Have you verified that the code gets as far as `form.submit()`?

Comment: @cookiemonster With a breakpoint in the Firefox console, yes.

Comment: We're missing some functions. Can you provide a full working example?

Comment: @PaulRichter Thanks for finding the comment.  That at least makes me feel better.  I'll try to create some equivalent (to jquery) javascript code and see if that helps.

Comment: @cookiemonster I think that's everything you'd need, one file.

Comment: Destroying the `button` with `span.innerHTML = ...` seems to kill it. Hiding the `button`, and inserting a new `em` element using `document.createElement()` fixes it. I created dummies of the missing functions so that I could run some tests.

Comment: ...don't use `.innerHTML` to change the state of your nodes. Treat them like they ought to be treated... as DOM nodes, not strings of HTML.

Comment: @cookiemonster Put that in an answer and the check is yours for the taking it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem based on comments left by cookiemonster who discovered that submit event disappeared in the innerHtml string was overwritten.

Now, I include the `<em>` tag inside the `<span>`, but set its display style type of the `<em>` tag to 'none'.  This way displaying the button is a matter of flipping the button `<input>` and `<em>` tags style display properties.  As long as they are out of phase, only one of the elements appear.  Which is exactly what I want.

```
// enabling button
em.style.display = 'none';
button.style.display = ''; 

// disabling button
em.style.display = '';
button.style.display = 'none';
```